Blazor Cross-Service DBContext modifications
I have been trying out Blazor Interactive Server for a bit and I am quite happy with it.
I am now at the point of creating a core for the application. In the architecture that I am targeting I want each Entity to have their own Service (ex: CarService, MakeService, ...). Some of these services perform complex operations and then store/modify/add an entity. The reason for each entity having its own service is separation of concerns and DRY, I don't want to have repeated code in other services that in addition should not have to know about business specifics of another service.
I want to achieve the following properties with the architecture:

I want to be able to create user interface where a user makes many changes, to potentially different types of entities - through my Entity Services - and the view simply has to call a single SaveChangesAsync on the DBContext. Such as when the user actively clicks the Save Button on the page.
I want to be able to call different entity services in another service and flush all changes at the end via a single SaveChangesAsync on the DBContext or defer that flush to the view.

Considering the following service definition:
public abstract class OrderService<TEntity> : ILXEntityService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private LXDBContext _dbContext;
    private AnalysisService _analysisService;

    public LXModelService(LXDBContext dbContext, AnalysisService analysisService)
    {
        this._dbContext = dbContext; // <-- Dependency Injection
        this._analysisService = analysisService;
    }

    // ...

    public async Task Deactivate(Order order) {

        // For simplicity without transaction in this example

        foreach (Analysis analysis in order.analyses) {
            await _analysisService.Deactivate(analysis); // <-- Calling another service
        }

        order.activefl = false;

    }

    // ...

}

I want to be able to do this:
@inject LXDBContext dbContext
@inject AnalysisService analysisService

<button @onclick="OnDeactivate()">Deactivate</button>
<button @onclick="OnSave()">Save</button>

@code {

   public async Task OnDeactivate() {
       await analysisService.Deactivate(lorder); // <-- Modification
   }

   public async Task OnSave() {
       await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); // <-- Saving
   }

}

Problem is, although this works when using a Scoped DBContext, Scoped DBContexts themselves lead to many problems such as the notorious

a second operation was started on this context instance before a
previous operation completed. this is usually caused by different
threads concurrently using the same instance of DBContext

This seems unavoidable in Blazor where you have multiple components / pages that hold the same (scoped) DBContext instance.
So the other solution is to use a transiant DBContext, or the per-operation dbcontext (which is the officially recommend way to use DBContext by microsoft). But using a transient or per-operation DBContext takes away all the benefits of using EF Core. Such as lazy-loading, Change Tracking, First-Level Cache, Unit of Work... At that point EF Core just becomes an ORM.
As mentioned transient DBContexts loose change tracking, which is a must have for the application we are building and size of our entities, where its not acceptable that EF Core tries to overwrite each property upon a save - including unmodified ones.
Since I am pretty new to Blazor, I figured people that have experience with working with Blazor and EF Core have a solution for this problem, but searching online did not provide me with any fruitful hints.

So the other solution is..., soultion is to fix error. It is a bug in 99%. Somewhere you have forgot await.

Also there is no automatic scopes in Blazor. Scope created for the entire session. Before requestiong OrderService, you have to create Scope and retrieve this service from newly created scope.

So is your application SSR or full interactive Blazor [you don't make it clear].

My apologies, my application is a Blazor Interactive Server application.

"But using a transient or per-operation DBContext takes away all the benefits of using EF Core. Such as lazy-loading, Change Tracking, First-Level Cache, Unit of Work... At that point EF Core just becomes an ORM."  Turn that around.  EF core is an ORM with a specific implementation on top of the core functionality that does what you describe.  However, to use that extra functionality you need to wed yourself to the cause.

See my answer for a longer commentary.  If you want to see a different way take a look at this Repo of mine.  https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo

Check this one OwningComponentBase

@LostSoul - I saw you comment on that old post.  Take a good look at my Repo for some alternative thinking.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv - OwningComponentBase has serious issues - see https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.OwningComponentBase.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis Thanks for answering. I've read your CodeProject articles before; appreciate you sharing your knowledge and experience.
"EF implements the Repository and Unit of Work patterns for you, so you only need a thin shim implementation in your infrastructure layer" - Correct in my initial design I keep my infrastructure layer slim because of that exact reason.
"If you want to use all the .. and change tracking then you wed yourselves to EF Core" - Okay, EF Core is an abstraction, so "weding" myself to EF Core is not necessarily a bad thing as it can be easily mocked etc

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I am not sure Change Tracking is only a mindset, but given your comments and other topics I have read online, I may need to rethink how I am using Blazor and why I am using it in a way that leads to problems instead of looking for direct solutions.

NP. You can still use change tracking - I do in all my Command implementations.  You just do it on a unit of work scale.  I use the aggregate concept to deal with all complex objects - there's the invoice example in the demo Repo.  I said mindset to get you thinking differently!  I use EF core as a ORM.

Note: This is only a commentary that is too big to fit in a comment.
Blazor Server creates a new type of context in which to execute database operations.
SSR and API operation are easy.  Database scoped services are short lived and exist for the duration of the HttpRequest.
A Blazor SPA can be long lived, just like a desktop application.  But with the issue that it's inherently async. That makes using a single long lived DB context a non starter [I tried in the early days of Blazor!] - a problem you've already identified.
The only solution is to use a DbContext factory to get short lived unit of work DbContexts.

"But using a transient or per-operation DBContext takes away all the benefits of using EF Core. Such as lazy-loading, Change Tracking, First-Level Cache, Unit of Work... At that point EF Core just becomes an ORM."

True, but if that's what you want, write a Desktop app.  No SPA can deliver that.
Turn that thought around.  EF Core is a ORM with a lot of added extras.  It implements the Repository and Unit of Work patterns for you, so you only need a thin shim implementation in your infrastructure layer.  If you want to use all the complex data object and change tracking then you wed yourselves to EFCore, long lived contexts and the inherent consequences.
"As mentioned transient DBContexts loose change tracking, which is a must have for the application we are building and size of our entities,.. "
That's only a mindset.
